# How do i backup all files listed in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am trying to backup the crontab entries structure and files running under crontab.

But I am stuck with how do i search files in `crontab -l` and copy the scripts running under it.

My possible ways

I have listed

```
crontab -l > test.txt 

cat test.txt
```

But how can I search the files after listing.

My entries are like:

```
# daily pingback report
30 1 * * * php /var/opx/cron-script/daily-email-reports/pingback_report.php | curl --data-binary @- https://pxc.com/email/send

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# daily jobs 02+ hours
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# daily Failed Device Search
0 2 * * *  /var/opx/cron-script/failed_device_search.sh

# daily Device Not Detected (we are not getting any of these, so commenting out)
# 5 2 * * *  /var/opx/cron-script/device_not_detected.sh

    # daily Failed App Search (we are not getting any of these, so commenting out)
    # 10 2 * * *  /var/opx/cron-script/failed_app_search.sh

    # daily oss event report (uncomment when dev db issue is fixed)
    10 3 * * * /var/opx/cron-script/event-analysis/daily-oss-event-report

    # Copy tomcat logs from s1 and s2 , compress them and move to S3 storage
    #30     21      *       *       *       /var/opx/cron-script/log_backup.sh
```

I want to copy scripts running in these entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for part in $(sed 's/#.*//' test.txt | while read t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 main; do echo $main; done); do
  echo $part
done | grep / | grep -v ://
```

For your example, this prints:

```
/var/opx/cron-script/daily-email-reports/pingback_report.php
/var/opx/cron-script/failed_device_search.sh
/var/opx/cron-script/event-analysis/daily-oss-event-report
```

I'm not proud of it, but it is fairly portable shell, and seems to work for the cases you've given.  You might need a smarter parser for more complex cases, or to handle more obscure words that may exist in your crontabs.

Answer (score 0):

This is my script useful if any one want to backup cron's

```
#!/bin/bash

    #This Script use for backup of crontab files and entries
    #Modify as per your need

    mkdir -p /mnt/cron_backups
    for part in $(crontab -l | grep -v "clientmqueue" | sed 's/#.*//' | while read t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 main; do echo $main; done); do
      echo $part
    done | grep / | grep -v :// | while read -r row
                                      do
                                        scp $row /mnt/cron_backups/
                                        crontab -l > /mnt/cron_backups/backup_cron.txt 
                                        tar -cvzf  /mnt/cron_backups.tar.gz /mnt/cron_backups/

                                      done
    # grep -v is used for ignoring specific script with specific words or character
```

Thanks to John....